# Gas Less ERC-20 Token Minting

Tags: remix, erc-20, tokens, gas, gas-refund

How can I create ERC-20 token on Ethereum blockchain without paying gas fee using Remix.ethereum.org

Please provide code to help
I saw Zeroswap DEX allow us to trade without paying gas fee.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do any transaction that's writing anything to Blockchain without paying gas. (ofcourse you can try with 0 gas price but no miner will pick it up and include it in a block.)

So, creating a token without gas is impossible.

But you can pay for the gas instead of user who uses your contract. This is the case of zero swap.

You can read this to understand how you can pay for the user.
https://medium.com/blockchannel/how-to-save-your-ethereum-dapp-users-from-paying-gas-for-transactions-cfc665891ab4

Answer (score 0):

indeed any transaction using gas (mint or other transactions,beacuese miners use it for handle transactions) but you can change transaction to somehow who pays gas, it calls "meta transaction", you can read more about gasless transactions [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/sending-gasless-transactions) and ERC20 meta transaction [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/ethereum-erc-20-meta-transactions-4cacbb3630ee).